# How to create dijit/Dialog with a DIV ID?

Tags: dialog, dojo, dijit.form

How to create a dijit/Dialog with a DIV ID?

Answer (score 1):

There is some really good reference information available here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/widget/Dialog.html

in addition, there are a variety of Dojo Dialog tests available here:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html

It wasn't clear what you meany by "width a DIV ID"?